# ROS2 Humble service call within a timer callback

Tags: callback, service

I have a system in which there are 2 component nodes in a single process. Both of them have a dedicated single-threaded executor (2 separate node containers). The first node needs to make a service call from a timer callback and the second one is the service server that just returns a value. For simplicity sake, the code below is a simplified version, but the functionality is the same.

```
// Node 1

client = this->create_client<std_srvs::srv::SetBool>("set_bool");
timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
    std::chrono::seconds(1),
    [this] ()
    {
        auto request = std::make_shared<std_srvs::srv::SetBool::Request>();
        request->data = true;
        auto future = client->async_send_request(request);
        try
        {
            auto response = future.get();
        }
        catch(const std::exception &e)
        {
            // error handle
        }
    }
);

// Node 2
service_server_ = this->create_service<std_srvs::srv::SetBool>(
    "set_bool",
    [this] (const std_srvs::srv::SetBool::Request::SharedPtr request, 
            const std_srvs::srv::SetBool::Response::SharedPtr response)
    {
        response->success = request->data;
        response->message = "Success";
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Service server callback ended");
    }
);
```

When I make a service request from the command line, I get the response with no issues. But when the service is called from the timer callback, the execution in the timer callback blocks on the future.get() line. The service server callback is executed without issue since the RCLCPP_INFO line is being printed inside the terminal.

I've also tried using the future.wait_for() function with a 1s timeout, and the result is always a std::future_status::timeout.

My thoughts are that the single threaded executor is blocked on the timer callback thus can't process the service call future.